# Tensorflow: run time increases per iteration

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am having issues with the running time of my program. The first iteration runs in 5 seconds, but the 20th in 50 seconds. I tried using the tf.reset_default_graph() command, but I get the following error:
"Tensor("Const:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg_1/Reshape_2:0", shape=(128,), dtype=float32)"

```
def ModelA(keep_probability, input_M, V_a, L):
# Do all kinds of matmul and reshape operations in this method like:
pred_matrix = tf.matmul(weights['W1'], input, M)
pred_matrix = tf.reshape(c, [d,d])

return pred_matrix

# Define Variables
 weights = {
'W1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[d, d], seed=seed), name="W1"),
'W2': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[d, d], seed=seed), name="W2"),
'W3': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[1, d], seed=seed), name="W3"),
'W4': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[d, d], seed=seed), name="W4"),
'W5': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[number_of_classes, d], 
seed=seed), name="W5")
}

# Load in data:
....

# Initialize and open session
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()  # Used to save the model
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# Define placeholders
M = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='M')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='Y')
V_a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='V_a')
keep_probability = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_probability')

for epoch in range(number_of_epochs):
    for x in range(number_of_batches):

    pred_matrix = ModelA(...)

    # Define cost function and optimizer
    cost_function = 
   tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred_matrix, 
    labels=pol_matrix_batch))
    optimizer = 
    tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost_function)

    _, cost, accuracy = sess.run([optimizer, cost_function, accuracy], 
    feed_dict={M: sen_matrix_batch,                                                                                   
    V_a: target_matrix_batch,                                                                                   
    Y: pol_matrix_batch,                                                                                   
    keep_probability: 0.8})
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I fixed the issue

Everything that involves `tf.operation` should be defined before the `tf.Session()` and should be run with the placeholders.

Comment: All `tf.operation` calls should be outside of your training loop. Each time those lines get run, operations are added to your computational graph. Thus the graph grows on each iteration, and then you see the slowdown. You should fully define your graph and all operations before starting the training loop, and not add any new operations inside the training loop.

Comment: Is this possible in my current code or do I have to rewrite my code? I change my data per batch, with which I do all those `tf.operations`. Isn't it possible to define a new session with the computed weights?

Comment: Simply define all required operations before starting your training loop. You can run them however many times you want for a single batch

Comment: But I still have to access these operations inside the training loop right? Can you please explain how to do this in my code?
(This is my first time using tensorflow)

Comment: @mikkola, I just fixed the issue. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mikkola already mentioned, you should put all tf. ... before you start the session. Otherwise, you will extend your computation graph which makes it very slow.